# How can I display number of words within my document?

Tags: word-count, texcount

For a magazine I have to write a small article of max. 700 words. I'd like to have a wordcount at the end. I found the following code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526304/232632) on StackExchange. But when I tried it myself it didn't work. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to respond to the topic.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\wordcount{\input{|"texcount -inc -sum -0 -template={SUM} \jobname.tex"}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eleifend pulvinar quam, vel suscipit urna tincidunt eget.

This document has \wordcount words.

\end{document}
```

I get the following Error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `|texcount -inc -sum -0 -template={SUM} test.tex'
> not found .
>
> Type X to quit or  to proceed, or enter new name. (Default
> extension: tex)
>
> Enter file name:

Does anybody knows what is going wrong?

Comment: My guess is that you didn't use the `-shell-escape` option.

Comment: Hi, do you have `texcount` installed? Are you calling LaTeX with `--shell-escape`? And BTW, counting the words in LaTeX is quite difficult... the expansion can create much more words than you have in the source!

Comment: I have no idea what the -shell-escape option means.

I downdloaded the texcount zip and unpacked it within the same folder as my test-document. This is sufficient, isn't it? (I'm not quite sure how it all works, but I'm eager to learn.)

Comment: For me it is fine to just count the words within a certain section. I don't use any codes within that section. Is there an easier solution for this problem? I'd like to display the words within the same document.

Answer (score 1):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip1em\parindent0pt
\immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum  \jobname.tex > wordcount.aux }
\begin{document}
\section*{How to compile this file}
From the command line (The damn buttonless  black window): \par
\hfil\texttt{pdflatex --shell-escape  \jobname .tex}\par  
From  your favourite  \LaTeX\ editor: \par
\hangindent1em\hangafter0 Edit your editor configuration to enable the  option \texttt{--shell-escape} of  the \texttt{pdflatex} compiler. You should {\em not} use this option by foreing  documents (like this) without know if the source is safe.\par

% This part is not counted
%TC:ignore 
 Word count = {\bfseries\large \input{wordcount.aux}}
%TC:endignore   
\end{document}
```