# Dynamically returning word counts in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, texcount

I'd like to be able to dynamically report in a table of contents the word count by section in my document. This way, when writing a manuscript with chapters, I can see the length of each section (chapter) as I write. Is there any way to do this (or a table of contents generator package that has this)?

Comment: LaTeX doesn't normally or easily count words.  There esits a separate program for that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526264/use-of-word-count-command?r=SearchResults&s=2|83.2668  Your best bet is to do a word count on the resulting PDF.  The only way I know of to add them to the TOC is manually using \addtocontents.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277734/11604